# Suppose you roll a pair of fair dice. What is the probability that the number of dots on the two dice sum to either $5$ or $10$?

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose you roll a pair of fair dice. What is the probability that the number of dots on the two dice sum to either $5$ or $10$?

(a) $5/36$
(b) $7/36$
(c) $11/36$
(d) $4/36$

So here are the possible combinations:

$\{4,1\}$
$\{2,3\}$
$\{5,5\}$
$\{6,4\}$

I don't know how you can derive $7/36$ from this.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The possible pairs are $i,j$, with $i,j \in \{1,...,6\}$.

Comment: 5+5 is a unique combination but 4+1 has a twin 1+4 etc.

Comment: Imagine the dice are red and green. Among the $36$ are $1$ on red and $4$ on green, but also $4$ on red and $1$ on green.

Comment: But as far as the total of the pair is concerned, 4,6 is the same as 6,4 and should not be counted twice.

Answer (score 1):

Draw up a table, and the result falls out immediately. 
You will see that the possible results are: {4,1}, {1,4}, {2,3}, {3,2}, {4,6}, {6,4} and {5,5}, out of the 36 possibilities; hence $\frac{7}{36}$, as each possibility is equally likely.

Answer (score 0):

You could get {4,1} or {1,4}. Same with {2,3} and {6,4}. There's only one way to get {5,5}, though.

Answer (score 0):

Let (a,b) = (Value for first dice, second dice).

Then we have

(1,4)
(4,1)
(2,3)
(3,2)
(5,5)
(6,4)
(4,6).